# ssh bash with whitespace?

Tags: bash, shell, ssh

Can anyone explain, please, why this command echoes an empty line instead of "abc"? I'm stuck with this. I know there are multiple ways of reaching the same goal but please also explain why this command does not print "abc" and why it's wrong.

```bash
ssh 127.0.0.1 bash -c "echo abc"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You effectively lose a level of quoting when you execute commands via `ssh`. You would need to write instead:

```
ssh 127.0.0.1 'bash -c "echo abc"'
```

Without those outside quotes, the command you're running on the remote system is:

```
bash -c echo abc
```

Here you're running the command `echo`, with `$0` set to `abc`.

Comment: Thanks for answer. But why `ssh 127.0.0.1 echo abc` works fine?

Comment: There's no quoting involved there. This problem only crops up when the removal of a quoting level changes the semantics of the command.